# Сортировка и relations в yii

Tags: php, yii

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть модель catalog, в которой есть отношение

```
'products'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Products' 'productcategories(category_id, product_id)'),
```

, а в модели Products в свою очередь есть отношение

```
'brand'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Brands', array('brand_id'=>'id')),
```

Вопрос в том, как мне в контроллере CatalogController организовать сортировку по названию бренда товара. Может кто-нибудь подсказать ?

Пробовал так:

```
$sort = new CSort();
    $sort->defaultOrder = 'discount_price asc';
    $sort->attributes = array(
        'name'=>array(
            'asc'=>'brand.name ASC',
            'desc'=>'brand.name DESC',
        ),
    );
```

И так:

```
$sort = new CSort();
    $sort->defaultOrder = 'discount_price asc';
    $sort->attributes = array(
        'name'=>array(
            'asc'=>'t.brand.name ASC',
            'desc'=>'t.brand.name DESC',
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Я не знал, что функция класса CSort принимает в качестве параметров непосредственно SQL запрос. Так что, если кому то будет нужно например, как мне, отсортировать товар по его бренду, то можно сделать так:

```
$sort = new CSort();
$sort->attributes = array(
   'name'=>array(
       'asc'=>'(SELECT name from tb_brands WHERE tb_brands.id = t.brand_id) ASC',
        'desc'=>'(SELECT name from tb_brands WHERE tb_brands.id = t.brand_id) DESC',
   ),
```

);